# How to count achievements after the game started?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Minecraft server with a couple friends on it. I was thinking of using the scoreboard function to track achievements so we could know each other's progression in the game. Problem being that the server has already been on for quite awhile and people have accumulated achievements already.

Is there a command in game to list number of achievements obtained or perhaps in the statistics of a player? This is then used to update the scoreboard with the starting values and then further track from then on.

MC version: 1.7.10
Modpack: FTB Resurrection

Answer (score 2):

The scoreboard command is big and complicated.  Go look at the [wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) for it first.

So, the first thing you need to do is set up a scoreboard objective for each achievement:

```
/scoreboard objective add acquireIron achievement.acquireIron
/scoreboard objective add bakeBread achievement.bakeBread
...
```

See the wiki for each of the achievements in vanilla Minecraft.  Note that Overpowered probably isn't available, since it was added in 1.8, and some mods can add other achievements.

You'll also need a a scoreboard objective to tally all the other achievements:

```
/scoreboard objective add tally dummy Achievments Taken
```

Now you'll need a clock, probably a fill clock, although not necessarily a 20Hz fill clock.  You'll need a clock that can trigger over 30 command blocks.

There's probably a better way to do the next step on a brand new server, but since that's not the case, I won't go into it.  The first command that needs to be run on each clock cycle is a reset of everyone's tally score:

```
scoreboard players set @a tally 0
```

Next we need to increment the tally score for each achievement taken:

```
scoreboard players add @a[score_acquireIron_min=1] tally 1
scoreboard players add @a[score_bakeBread_min=1] tally 1
...
```

That's it for commands that need to be run on a clock.  The only important thing is that the tally score gets reset first, and that every achievement score is checked before the tally score gets reset again.

Finally, you need some way to display this to the server.  I would suggest the tab list:

```
/scoreboard objective setdisplay list tally
```

---

***Disclaimer:** I haven't tested this myself, as I'm away from my desktop computer and a Minecraft installation.  I'm pretty sure I haven't missed anything obvious, so this should work fine.*

Comment: Am i right to assume there is no way to just tally all the achievements as a whole and has to be done individually? The problem being theres over 100+ mods and the achievements added are on the scale of more than 100. If this is the case, is there an alternative addon/serverside mod that can just pull achievement info from the player data to do this?

Comment: It might be possible to do it just using `achievement` criteria, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: using the achievement as a criteria returns "Invalid objective criteria type 'achievement'"

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might.  It was worth a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using advancements pack by BlazeandCav, you can enter those commands

You can get the scoreboard to show up on the sidebar using the following command:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Advancements
```

Or on the player list that shows up when you press tab:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list Advancements
```